# Sliding window part broken

Tags: mounting, vinyl, window-frame

Does anybody know how is it called this part? Is taken from a sliding double pane window that I have no idea about what brand/model it is. I found them broken, both the upper and the lower.
[image]
It goes mounted here
[image]
[image]

Have no idea how to search for to buy it online, just probably go to HD and ask someone.....

Comment: take it to a glass shop

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. It is called pivot bar after searching through the internet just by images. On a 10 miles radius from my location at all glass shops and big boxes like HD/Lowes no one knows how it is called they even don't know where is coming from.

Comment: You need to go to a window wholesaler or manufacturer, not a big box store staffed with teenagers nor a glass shop. I happen to have a few window/door manufacturers/wholesalers close to where I live, but they rarely have parts that can be substituted for other manufacturers'. Usually the answer is "buy a new one."